# moving data from one column to another when there are NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data_frame(
     unique = c(1,2,3,4),
     lat = c(NA, 87.6, 78.6, 67.7),
     latitude= c(34.5, NA, 45.6, 34.8))
```

What I would like to do is when there is an 'NA' in lat  (for example in column 1 'lat' has an NA) the value from latitude is taken. So I would end up with a new column called 'latitude_new' that looks like `(34.5, 87.6, 45.6, 34.8)`.

I'm sure this can be done using 'mutate from dplyr, I'm just not quite sure how?

Comment: The output you describe is if you replace `NA`s in column `latitude` and not in column `lat`. If you want to replace `NA`s in `lat`, as you say, then the output should be `34.5, 87.6, 78.6, 67.7`

Comment: will delete as duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `dplyr::coalesce` replace all NA's with first  non-missing values

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% mutate(latitude_new = coalesce(lat,latitude))

    # A tibble: 4 x 4
    unique   lat latitude latitude_new
    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
    1      1  NA       34.5         34.5
    2      2  87.6     NA           87.6
    3      3  78.6     45.6         78.6
    4      4  67.7     34.8         67.7
```

Comment: Good alternative of `ifelse` :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also consider to use `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)

d2 <- d %>%
  mutate(latitude_new = ifelse(is.na(lat), latitude, lat))
d2
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   unique   lat latitude latitude_new
#    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1      1  NA       34.5         34.5
# 2      2  87.6     NA           87.6
# 3      3  78.6     45.6         78.6
# 4      4  67.7     34.8         67.7
```

The base R syntex is

```
d$latitude_new <- with(d, ifelse(is.na(lat), latitude, lat))
```

or

```
d2 <- transform(d, latitude_new = ifelse(is.na(lat), latitude, lat))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmin`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   mutate(latitude_new = pmin(lat, latitude, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   unique   lat latitude latitude_new    
#   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
#1      1  NA       34.5         34.5
#2      2  87.6     NA           87.6
#3      3  78.6     45.6         45.6
#4      4  67.7     34.8         34.8
```